# Import jQuery in React inside single component

Tags: reactjs

I want to import jQuery inside reactjs only inside 1 component because of the performance of the app but it doesn't work i keep getting error that **'$' is not defined** when using jQuery inside the page

what i want to do something like this :

```
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js";
```

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDN should be placed in `index.html` file not in `js` and then in you can use it in `React` component. You can't bundle `CDN` inside your JS, this againist the goal of having it on `CDN`. Check `webpack` externals https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: but if i added CDN inside index.html it will be loaded inside the whole app , also the $ is still not defined even when I import $ , should i ( npm i jquery ) and use it instead ? also does it affect the whole app ?

Comment: Cdn in index.html or install with npm will be available for whole app, that's why I explained that you can not bundle for single component @RazorJhon

Comment: npm is easier than importing an external link module , i will use npm instead , thank you for explanation